# Configure SSMS intellisense / web browser settings to accept UNC directory path inputs

Tags: sql-server, ssms, intellisense

I would like to navigate to open a directory path from an in-line commented UNC path. SSMS integrates with [Windows Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173887%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and Explorer allows UNC navigation from the address bar.

Indeed, when in the integrated browser, it is possible to navigate among UNC paths. HOWEVER, the click-thru functionality provided for `http:/` prefaced URLs in the text editor of SSMS does not seem to exist for UNC paths. The <kbd>Web Browser</kbd> section of <kbd>Options</kbd> / <kbd>Environment</kbd> appears to open Internet Explorer options and the <kbd>Text Editor</kbd> / <kbd>Plain Text</kbd> / <kbd>General</kbd> section has the "Enable single-click URL navigation option", but does not appear to allow definition of what is detected as a URL.

Screenshots linked below

[image: UrlAllowsClickThrough]

[image: UncDoesNotAllowClickthrough]

[image: TextEditor_PlainText_General]

(added sample code below)

```
use [master]
go

-- http://www.google.com
-- \\servername\unc\BackupFolder\

select 'This query needs to be uploaded to the URL' Header
union
select 'and also saved for archiving at the UNC path'
union
select 'so is it possible to clickthrough to both?'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you need to use [file URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/file-uris-in-windows):

For example:

[image: SSMS Screengrab - Local]

You can use UNC paths in a file uri if you convert the `\` to `/` like this:

[image: SSMS Screengrab - Share]